# Ruby on Rails Undo where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my routes.rb:

```
get 'people',         to: 'people#index'
get 'people/:person', to: 'people#person'
```

This is my controller:

```
def index
  @result = People.complicated_stuff
                  .sum(:amount)

  # more queries without .where(person: p)
  # more code
end

def person
  p = params[:person]

  @result = People.complicated_stuff
                  .where(person: p)
                  .sum(:amount)

  # more queries with .where(person: p)
  # more code
end
```

I would like to have this code more DRY, because the code is the same, except for the whereclause. So i thought about joining te two together into a seperate method. How can I undo all the where clauses with (Person: p)?
The only thing I came up with was:

```
def my_method(person: nil, select_all: true)
  if select_all
    p = People.distinct.pluck[:person]
  else
    p = person
  end

  @result = People.complicated_stuff
                  .where(person: p)
                  .sum(:amount)
end
```

But that gives a very ugly query.

### Edit

I just discovered this works also, and I think it's good enough for me:
I changed my routes.rb that both go to 'people#index'. And in my controller:

```
def index
  @p = params[:person]
  person = @p.nil? ? "" : "people.person = ?"

  @result = People.complicated_stuff
                  .where(person, @p)
                  .sum(:amount)
end
```

I never knew that worked.

Comment: I definitely don't like functions with booleans, because that means a function can take two different paths. You can for sure write it like `@result = People.complicated_stuff; @result = @result.where(person: params[:person]) if action_name.eql?("person"); @result = @result.sum(:amount)`

Comment: I did know about your solution, but than I have to split each query that i have into 3 multiple lines, each time with the same if statement. I was looking for a way to replace the whereclause in all queries?

Comment: ok, fair enough. I prefer that approach instead of deleting a `where`. If you really want to do that, you can use `unscope`, for more info no how to use it look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope

Comment: That gives also 3 multiple statements per query: `@result = People.complicated_stuff.where(person: params[:person]); @result = @result.unscope(person: params[:person]) if action_name.eql?("person"); @result = @result.sum(:amount)`

Comment: But if I understand correctly there isn't any way to put something at the questionmark, which will returns all rows in: `.where(person: ?)` (even the nil)

Comment: do you want all distinct people ?, if not, you could do `.where(if_something ? { person: params[:person] } : "1 = 1")`

Answer (score 0):

You could break the query scope out into a private method on your controller. Here's an example of what it might look like:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  def index 
    result
  end

  def people
    result
  end

  private

  def people_scope
    @people_scope ||= People.complicated_stuff
  end

  def person_scope
    # Depending on your use-case, it may make sense to memoize this
    person_id = params[:person]
    people_scope.where(person: person_id)
  end

  def result
    # If you want a one-liner, you could do this:
    # @result ||= params[:person] ? person_scope.sum(:amount) : people_scope.sum(:amount)
    # Personally, I like the readability and ease of debugging of the if/else statement
    @result ||= if params[:person]
                  person_scope.sum(:amount)
                else
                  people_scope.sum(:amount)
                end
  end
end
```

This is just one technique to DRY up the controller a bit. You could go so far as to call `result` in a `before_action`. I would caution against that, however. IMO, readable code with low cognitive overhead is better than 100% DRY code.